# Objective C initWithNibName

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, nib, init

I am facing some difficulties figuring out what this function in the Apple tutorials stands for:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
```

My questions are: what does the "@" stand for before MyViewController?

Addionally, as I am following [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html) tutorial, I was wondering: There are to nibs in my project: the automatically generated MainWindow.xib and MyViewController.xib – I was wondering: why do I have two if I only need one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @-sign before a string literal means that the string is an instance of NSString.

```
@"Hello" <-- NSString object
"Hello"  <-- Null-terminated char array (C-string)
```

You can even send messages to it:

```
[@"Hello" stringByAppendingString:@" World!"]
```

You will use NSString objects more often than C-strings.

If you want to convert a C-string to an NSString object (if you are using C libraries that return such strings for example), you could use this:

```
char *myCstring = "Hello, World!";
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myCstring];
```

---

About the two nibs: actually you don't need any nibs at all, but Apple likes to decrease performance by using a nib that only has one window. I don't know why they do it, but you can create a window in code with only one line, which compiles and runs much faster.

In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
// now you can remove the MainWindow.xib nib.
```

Personally I prefer to use no nibs at all, but that's one's own choice.

Comment: Thanks! Why is the char-array null-terminated? And: can I convert it to an NSString object?

Comment: Really? I prefer making windows in code, but Apple never show me how to do it. Could you? It's really important to me! Thanks!

Comment: In C, strings are always [terminated by a null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). You can convert it to an NSString object but you generally don't need to use a C-string unless you are using C libraries (e.g. SQLite).